# Regex conditional lookout

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

My input text file is like

```
A={5,6},B={2},C={3}
B={2,4}
A={5},B={1},C={3}
A={5},B={2},C={3,4,QWERT},D={TXT}
```

I would like to match all the lines where A=5,B=2 and C=3. The catch is, if variable is not mentioned, then that variable can take any value and hence that line also needs to be matched.

Above should match line 1,2 & 4.

I tried

```
.*?(?:(?=A)A\{.*?5).*?(?:(?=B)B\{.*?2).*?(?:(?=C)C\{.*?3)
```

https://regex101.com/r/NN9qk5/1

But, it is not working

I shall be using this regex in a python 3.6 code.

Comment: Try `^(?!.*?A=[^5]).*?\bB=2\b.*`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/0S0yre/1

Comment: Probably, `^(?!.*\bA=(?!5\b)\d+).*\bB=2\b.*` will work for you. It will make sure there is a number after `A=` that is not `5` if there is any `A`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Nn5jn/1). BTW, `(?=B)B` = `B`, the lookahead is redundant here (as it requires `B` to be `B`). `=` are not special, no need to escape them here.

Comment: I can confirm that the above regex posted by @WiktorStribiżew works as intended.

Comment: I think I over simplified the problem with only 2 variables. Hence I have changes my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve it with a regex, you may use

```
^
 (?!.*\bA={(?![^{}]*\b5\b))
 (?!.*\bB={(?![^{}]*\b2\b))
 (?!.*\bC={(?![^{}]*\b3\b))
.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YeHFjR/1)

The point is to fail a match if there is a key that contains no given number value inside braces.

E.g. `(?!.*\bA={(?![^{}]*\b5\b))` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is no 
 - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
 - `\bA` - a whole word `A` 
 - `={` - `={` substring 
 - `(?![^{}]*\b5\b)` - that is not followed with any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` and then followed with `5` as a whole word.

[Sample usage](https://ideone.com/JL4X1A) in Python 3.6:

```
import re
s = """A={5,6},B={2},C={3}
B={2,4}
A={5},B={1},C={3}
A={5},B={2},C={3,4,QWERT},D={TXT}"""
given = { 'A': '5', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}

reg_pattern = ''
for key,val in given.items():
    reg_pattern += r"(?!.*\b{}={{(?![^{{}}]*\b{}\b))".format(key,val)

reg = re.compile(reg_pattern)

for line in s.splitlines():
    if reg.match(line):
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
A={5,6},B={2},C={3}
B={2,4}
A={5},B={2},C={3,4,QWERT},D={TXT}
```

Note the use of `re.match`, this method only searches for a match at the start of the string, so, no need adding `^` anchor (that matches string start).

Comment: This exactly meets my requirement. Thanks